# how to limit find command's output used with option -print0

Tags: bash, find, awk

I'd like to limit output of find command. In the past I used to use for this ls command, e.g:

```
ls *tgz|head -100|xargs -i mv "{}" ../
```

but I got to know that the result may be unpredictable if name of file contains new line character. So more correct way to do this is something like that:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0
```

But taking this approach I'm not able to limit output of find with head command - it shows all file names separated with ^@ special sign:

```
 find . -name '*tgz' -print0|head -2|less
```

> file1.tgz^@file2.tgz^@file3.tgz^@file4.tgz^@file5.tgz^@

Is there a method to work this awkwardness away?

I tried to resolve it with help of awk:

```
find . -name 'BATCHED*' -print0|awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}'
```

but it still displays either all or zero lines.

May it be solved with help of awk? Is there better solution?

BTW. I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/112144/how-to-limit-unix-find-results-number) very instructive reference but there is not answer on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another opportunity for [safe `find`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    let ++count
    if [[ count -gt 10 ]]
    then
        unset count
        break
    fi
    printf "$REPLY"
    printf "$\x00"
done 9< <( find /full/path -print0 )
```

To verify, simply pipe it into this:

```
while IFS= read -r -d ''
do
    echo "START${REPLY}END"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this post. It works fine. There is one thing I don't understand: what does `done 9< <( find /full/path -print0 )` mean in this context? I'm used to application of `done < "Filename"` pattern, but I don't know this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's using file descriptor number 9 instead of stdin. That way you can use stdin in the loop (`cat`/`ssh`) without worrying about your loop terminating after the first file because the whole stream was swallowed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from `xargs` being word-orientated, while commands like `head` and `tail` are line-orientated.  One solution could be to not use `xargs` but instead [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have never heard about GNU parallel before. BTW - once I checked this webpage I saw one more answer - do you know maybe what happened to it?

Comment: Nope, I haven't got a clue what happened to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the --max-args or --max-lines argument to xargs, depending on your input format:

```
# Run less on no more than two files at a time
find . -type f -print0 | xargs --null --max-args=2 less
```