# Linux how to move n files out of nested subodirectories from a directory to another one

Tags: linux, file-transfer, file-management, move

I have a directory `invasive/` which contains 60000 files. I want to move only 1000 files out of nested sub-directories from `invasive/` to `invasive2/`

I tried to do the following:
`find invasive/ -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered -t invasive2/ {} + | head -1000`

Unfortunately it does work. Any idea ?

Comment: Should we count attempts to move? or *successful* move operations only?

Comment: I will say successful move operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Analysis

In your try:

> ```
> find invasive/ -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered -t invasive2/ {} + | head -1000
> ```

`head` gets no input at all because `find` does not print anything.

If you did

```
find … -print -exec mv … {} + | head …
```

or

```
find … -exec mv … {} + -print | head …
```

then `head` would get some input and exit, `find` could get `SIGPIPE`; but in general the signal wouldn't happen precisely when you need it. This is because `-exec … {} +` substitutes `{}` with possibly many pathnames, a bunch of pathnames.

- In case of `… -print -exec …` `-print` acts first for many pathnames that are going to form a bunch for `-exec … {} +`. If `SIGPIPE` happens then `-exec` won't be performed for the bunch.
- In case of `… -exec … {} + -print` `-exec` acts first for the whole bunch, only then `-print` prints for each pathname separately. `SIGPIPE` can happen only when the tool prints something, so it cannot interrupt `-exec mv`, it can only interrupt `-print`. If `SIGPIPE` happens, it will prevent `find` from printing more pathnames; but `-exec mv …` has already happened for the whole bunch.

You want to count only successful move operations. If `mv` tries to move multiple files and succeeds, then you know all the files were moved. If it fails then you cannot easily know how many files were moved. For this reason you need a separate `mv` for each file you're trying to move. So you need `-exec mv … \;` rather than `-exec mv … {} +` (besides `-exec … {} +` is not useful as a test in `find` anyway, it always returns true).

Another complication is you cannot be sure `-print` prints exactly one line per file (because pathnames may contain newline characters). A reliable solution is `-printf '\n'` (if your `find` supports `-printf`) or `-exec printf '\n' \;`.

This leads us to the following solution (flawed though):

```sh
# flawed
find invasive/ -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered -t invasive2/ {} \; -printf '\n' \
| head -n 999 >/dev/null
```

In theory it works like this:

- If and only if `mv` succeeds, a newline is printed.
- `head` terminates after 999 newlines, i.e. after 999 successful move operations. The sole disappearance of `head` does not cause `find` to immediately receive `SIGPIPE`. After 999 successful move operations `head` is no more, but `find` still works.
- `find` will receive `SIGPIPE` only if it tries to print something after `head` terminates. This happens after the 1000th successful move operation.

In practice there is no guarantee `head` reads fast enough and terminates fast enough to cause `SIGPIPE` exactly when we need it. This is the flaw in the above code. There's a buffer between `find` and `head`. It may happen `find` manages to print more lines than `head` is instructed to read. The mechanics of the pipe is designed to terminate the preceding tool (here: `find`) *eventually*, not precisely at exact moment; we cannot rely on it when we want to interrupt our `find` exactly after 1000 successful move operations.

Relaying on the *output* of `head` is not flawed this way. Something like

```
find … -print | head -n 1000 | code_that_runs_mv
```

is a good start, but since pathnames in general may contain newline characters, you need `-print0` (which is not portable), `head -z` (also not portable) and so on. And if you want to count successful move operations then it should rather be:

```
find … -print0 | code0_that_runs_mv_and_counts
```

It's possible to build working `code0_that_runs_mv_and_counts` as a shell script, at least in Bash. My attempt is below.

---

#### Solution

```sh
find invasive/ -type f -print0 | bash -c '
   counter=1000
   while [ "$counter" -gt 0 ] && IFS= read -r -d "" pathname; do
      </dev/tty mv --backup=numbered -t invasive2/ "$pathname" && ((counter--))
   done
' code0_that_runs_mv_and_counts
```

Note I used `</dev/tty mv …` to prevent `mv` from consuming stdin in case it prompts for confirmation or something. Well, with `--backup=numbered` I guess it shouldn't prompt; but in general it might and we don't want it to read anything from our `find`.

The code from above is not portable, I don't like it very much.

---

#### Portable* solution

If your `find` does not support `-print0` or you cannot use `bash` (or you simply enjoy more portable code) then consider the following approach:

```sh
while :; do echo; done | head -n 999 | find invasive/ -type f -exec sh -c '
   for pathname do
      </dev/tty mv --backup=numbered -t invasive2/ "$pathname" \
      && { read dummy || { kill -s PIPE "$PPID"; exit 0; } }
   done
' find-sh {} +
```

***** AFAIK the only non-portable thing here is `mv` with the options *you* used. If you didn't use `--backup=numbered`, then we could rewrite this `mv` to a portable form. Everything I added is portable, that's why I called this solution portable.

This is how the code works:

- `find` starts `sh` and passes possibly many pathnames to it as arguments. There may be more than one `sh` started one after another, the number doesn't matter.
- `sh` attempts to `mv` files one by one in a loop. After a successful move operation it tries to `read` exactly one line from its stdin inherited from `find`.
- `while … | head -n 999` (which could be `yes | head -n 999`, but `yes` is not portable) generates exactly 999 lines. Unless we run out of files first, exactly 999 `reads` will succeed. The `read` after the 1000th successful move operation will be the first `read` that fails.
- Failed `read` occurs exactly after the 1000th successful move operation. It causes two things:

  - `find` (`$PPID`, the parent process of `sh`) gets `SIGPIPE`, so it won't start more `sh` processes;
  - the current `sh` exits, so it won't process more pathnames.

---

#### Notes

- All the snippets are designed to move 1000 files; some contain `1000`, some contain `999` in the code. You can adjust them to move N files, but pay attention if you need N or N-1 in the code.
- Counting successful move operations makes sense, but in some circumstances it may cause a potential problem. When moving a file between filesystems, `mv` creates a copy, then deletes the source. A failure in deletion causes `mv` to report non-zero exit status, but the copy remains. Imagine your `invasive/` is read-only for you. In such scenario our code will copy regular files to `invasive2/` but no `mv` will count as successful. All the regular files will be copied.
- I used `bash -c '…' code0_that_runs_mv_and_counts`, `find … -exec sh -c '…' find-sh {} +`. If you are surprised by `code0_that_runs_mv_and_counts` and `find-sh` being arguments then read [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the `head` command on the `find` output. Something **like** this (in a prodution environment with very valuable data, please test intensive)

```
find invasive/ -type f -print0 | head -z -n 1000 | xargs -0 -r -n 1 mv --backup=numbered -t invasive2
```

Update:

The comments are totally right. I always forget about "special characters" like newlines. I added the "zero termination". Thanks for the comments!

see `man xargs`:

- `-n 1` means one argument per command
- `-r` means do not run if empty
- `-0` means incoming arguments are terminated by zero (`\0`)

see `man head`:

- `-z` means incoming arguments are terminated by zero (`\0`)

see `man find`:

- `-print0` means teminate outgoing strings by zero (`\0`)

Comment: thanks. It works perfectly :-)